# How to switch/transition an Ember route from third party library?

Tags: javascript, web-applications, ember.js

I'm having difficulty integrating Ember.js with a third party control (fancytree). In this case, I want the tree nodes to show different Ember views on the main content area.

Right now, while rendering the nodes, I'm wrapping them into a tags pointing to '#/a', '#/b', etc..  other option I though of would be using `window.location = url;` to switch to the appropriate route.

It's working but I'm learning Ember and would like to know if this is the best way of doing this..

**Is there an 'Ember' way of doing this? Or what I'm doing is how this is usually done?**

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if my way is the correct Ember way but it is working for me. I added in the namespace (in my case 'App') the application controller:

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    init: function() {
        this._super();
        App.controllerHelper = this;
    },
});
```

You can now call with this helper the `transitionToRoute` method from everywhere:

```
App.controllerHelper.transitionToRoute('your route' [, dynamic id]);
```

I hope this helps and please correct me if there is a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API). Ember's router should be able to pick up the state changes and transition accordingly.